# Google Analytics on AMP page not reporting traffic

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

I'm trying to get Google Analytics to work on my AMP landing pages. I have followed [this guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/) for how to setup the analytics on how to include it on each page.

The config looks like this

```
<amp-analytics type=“googleanalytics” id="main_tracking">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
        "vars": {
            "account": "UA-49671924-1"
        },
        "extraUrlParams": {
            "cd1": "{{_country}}",
            "cd2": "{{_language}}"
        },
        "triggers": {
            "trackPageview": {
                "on": "visible",
                "request": "pageview"
            },
            "trackEvent": {
                "on": "visible",
                "request": "event",
                "vars": {
                    "eventCategory": "amp",
                    "eventAction": "viewed_amp"
                }
            }
        },
        "trackClickOnHeader": {
            "on": "click",
            "selector": "#header",
            "request": "event",
            "vars": {
                "eventCategory": "ui-components",
                "eventAction": "header-click"
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

But when I run the pages, the console returns the following errors.

> [AmpAnalytics main_tracking]" "No request strings defined. Analytics
>   data will not be sent from this page."
>
> [AmpAnalytics main_tracking]" "Ignoring event. Request string not
>   found: " "pageview"
>
> [AmpAnalytics main_tracking]" "Ignoring event. Request string not
>   found: " "event"

On the Google Analytics side, nothing seems to be recorded.

Now I can't find much about this error, if anything, but I'm assuming it refers to the requests object needed if you want to [send analytics to a custom URL](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-analytics). But I don't understand why this is being requested when trying to run Google Analytics

Does anyone know if something is missing, and what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using smart quotes here

```
type=“googleanalytics”
```

If you remove the smart quotes and use normal quotes it should work i.e. like this:

```
type="googleanalytics"
```

Comment: The error is gone but no data being sent to Google Analytics, but I'm guessing that is a separate issue since I'm no longer getting the error message I mentioned in my question

Comment: I'd recommend stripping out most of the analytics code, and building up from the bare minimum e.g.
 ```<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
      "vars": {
        "account": "UA-XXXXXXX-X"
      },
      "triggers": {
        "trackPageview": {
          "on": "visible",
          "request": "pageview"
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
    </amp-analytics>```
You should be able to see the pageviews immediately in GA with the above config

Comment: Hey, rodders, thank you for that info. Turns out that that internal traffic is not recorded in our Analytics, the tracking has been working fine since I fixed the quotes, just noticed traffic on the AMP pages today.